# Unable to access stackexchange sites from this system

Tags: support, 404-not-found

Earlier, I was not able to access most of the stackexchange sites like stackoverflow, programmers.SE etc. on my home Windows XP system. I was able to access only a few like http://meta.stackexchange.com and not even http://www.meta.stackexchange.com (note the www). I tried many other sites like http://www.stackoverflow.com, http://area51.stackexchange.com/ but was getting `page not found` errors on all browsers. Even pinging from terminal was saying `destination host unreachable`. I did not check recently but may be all SE sites are unreachable now.

I was clueless about what could be the issue. I thought some firewall issue? So, I stopped AVG antivirus's firewall, then completely uninstalled it and even turned of windows firewall.
But still not reachable even after fresh installation of Windows 7.

Then I noticed a "Too many requests" notice on google. This page -

http://www.google.co.in/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.co.in/#

I don't know why this appeared but I guess somehow too many requests might have been sent to these sites and they blocked me. But in that case, SE would be smart enough to show a captcha like google.

So, how to confirm the problem and fix it.  Similar questions like these don't look solved yet  -

[Unable to access certain websites](https://superuser.com/questions/145067/unable-to-access-certain-websites)
[Unable to Access Certain Websites](https://superuser.com/questions/76240/unable-to-access-certain-websites)

I have lately started actively participating in lots of SE sites. There are new new questions popping up in my mind every time and I am not able to ask them. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your system is not infected by booting it off a bootable anti-virus media. Check that you're running it with updated signatures.

Afterwards try to get another ip address by reconnected your router to the internet and see whether the problem still persists. If so, please try to access the pages from a linux-live-cd. In case that won't work either, please check your router settings.

Comment: ["Have you tried turning it off and on again?"™](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt9j80Jkc_A)